# Jquery toggle() - detect show/hide state and add arrows

Tags: css, toggle

I am using `.toggle()` to show/hide a div.

I want to identify the state (show vs hide) and add an arrow - upwards for show - downwards for hide, I have one image which is upwards, how to use css transform to toggle between the images?

Also how do I detect the state and add the arrow?

```
 <div id="abc">text<span class="arrows"></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
span.arrows{
    background:url(arrows_png); 
    padding:15px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d looks fine to me…

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by selecting it with the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector and check the `length`

```
if($('#abc:visible').length>0) {
   //element is visible
}
```